# Is there a way to create an indicator somewhere on the Ubuntu desktop, which shows that control key is being pressed?

Tags: gnome

I want an indicator that will show if the control key is pressed at the moment. So it will turn on when the key is pressed and turn off when the key is released.

Comment: AFAIK there's no such thing.

Comment: `screenkey` is a tool that shows the typed keys - useful for screencasts